# IIS Formal Brotli compression module

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, compression, gzip

Is there any formal extension for IIS to support brotli compression? Previously I saw these two extension but I cannot rely on them for a production server:

- https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2016/03/iis-brotli
- https://my.we-amp.com/downloads/iisbrotli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will release an official IIS Brotli extension soon, and it is an open-source project:

https://github.com/Microsoft/IIS.Compression

Check the official docs:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview